# PHP Chat System (Show all Messages ORDER by Date)

Tags: php

I have a problem, but he does not sort all the messages after the date. Of course the newest messages should always be on top.

Watch a example at my page: http://test.liscon.bplaced.net/messages.php

```
<?php 
$user = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user.id, user.username, user.image FROM user;");
if(!$user->execute()) {
    print_r($user->errorInfo());
}           
?>
<?php

     while($row = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
     <form class="left" action="" method="GET">
     <?php                  
         if($stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user.id, msg.id, 
             msg.user_id, msg.sender_id, msg.message, msg.date                      
             FROM msg
             INNER JOIN user
                 ON msg.user_id = user.id || 
                    msg.sender_id = user.id                     
             WHERE msg.user_id = :user_id AND sender_id = :sender_id || 
                   msg.user_id = :sender_id AND msg.sender_id = :user_id 
             ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;")
           )
           {
               $stmt->BindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['id']);
               $stmt->BindParam(':sender_id', $row['id']);                      

               if(!$stmt->execute()) {
                   print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
               }
           }
      ?>
```

[Table structur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24VmL.png)

Comment: can share the table structure?

Comment: There is a `LIMIT 1` in your query to get the message, so you only ever get the one newest message per user. Is that intended, and are you asking here how to sort this list of one message per user by date instead of user? Then you would need one query with a join or subquery instead of two queries. BTW: the join with `user` in the inner query looks suspicious; why do you even need the join?

Comment: Yes, I edit my Topic. You see there  a Table Structur. I want to list all new Messages at the Top.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try changing your query like below?

```
ON (msg.user_id = user.id || msg.sender_id = user.id)
    WHERE (msg.user_id = :user_id AND sender_id = :sender_id) OR (msg.user_id = :sender_id AND msg.sender_id = :user_id) ORDER BY `msg.date` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Let me know if it works or not?

Thanks,
Smit Raval

Comment: What error are you getting? Or print the output of your code.

Comment: I get no errors but It does not Sort the new Comment by Date. He only sort the Message By Date.

Comment: You have asked to sort messages by date in your question. You have mentioned nothing about comments!!

Comment: I cant see even a query in your code to fetch comments? @local17

Comment: Sorry I mean *messages*. He shows me all the new messages, but not sorted by date. That means if I have a message that was sent at 8pm and one that was sent 10 minutes ago, it will be displayed first at 8pm

Comment: Can you please show the table and how you are storing date?

Comment: Can you please post two dates from your table rows?

Comment: (1, 12, 10, 'Hallo', '2018-03-10 03:42:09', '2018-03-10 18:17:31'),


(2, 10, 3, 'NEW', '2018-03-10 04:30:30', '2018-03-10 18:26:23'),

Comment: I think its a issue with the column name date. date is a reserved keyword in mysql can you try adding `` in order by? like

ORDER BY `msg.date`

Not sure but please try if it helps? I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: Sorting works, but it affects the message. That is, it sorts the newest item by date. Order by Date works. Only with Messages. But it just does not show up. Your function does not change, it stays the same

Comment: i think the problem is here : <?php 
$user = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user.id, user.username, user.image FROM user;");
if(!$user->execute()) {
    print_r($user->errorInfo());
}           
?>
<?php

     while($row = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>

Comment: Sorting works then what is the issue? I have added `` in my function. I think you have got your answer? or still getting error?

Comment: I want to Sort all new messages at the Top. But it does not Work, you can see on my Page, If you write a message to anyone, it is not directed upwards

Comment: It is a display problem. You need to change your display code. If you are getting data in desc format.